# Micronaut Data MySQL database connection autoreconnect not working

Tags: mysql, jdbc, micronaut

I have below connection string for  MySQL database. It works fine during startup,after some idle time MySQL connection dropped by not reconnecting.

What other properties we need to include to keep the connection alive?

```
datasources:
  default:
    url:  ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:mysql://dbhost/DB?autoReconnect=true`}
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: ${JDBC_USER}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}        
    dialect: MYSQL
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 41,608,139 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the
server was 41,608,144 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

I have included tomcat jars in my projects.

```
compileOnly "io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor:$micronautDataVersion"
implementation "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:2.2.2"
implementation "io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc:$micronautDataVersion" 
implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-tomcat"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added these settings.It keeps the connection alive.

```
datasources:
  default:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    url:  ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:mysql://dbhost/DB?autoReconnect=true`}
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: ${JDBC_USER}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD}            
    dialect: MYSQL
    jmxEnabled: true
    initialSize: 5
    maxActive: 50
    minIdle: 5
    maxIdle: 25
    maxWait: 10000
    maxAge: 600000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
    validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
    validationQueryTimeout: 3
    validationInterval: 15000
    testOnBorrow: true
    testWhileIdle: true
    testOnReturn: false
    jdbcInterceptors: "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
```